# Running query method on kendo ui grid returns no changes

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to run the query method to filter the grid based on an id value. The following is the function that grabs the ids and the data source and sets up the options for the query.

Code:

```
function retrieve() {
        me.selectedLocationIds = me.selectedItems.selectedLocationIds;
        me.selectedProductIds = me.selectedItems.selectedProductIds;
        var gridDataSource = me.PriceGrid.dataSource;
        var options = {
            sort: gridDataSource.options.sort,
            filter: buildFilters(),
            page: 1,
            pageSize: gridDataSource.options.pageSize
        };
        gridDataSource.query(options)
)
```

The filters are being created in a function called BuildFilters(). Here are the filters as shown in the console:

[image: Filters from console]

The query is running with no errors and I am getting an http response, but there are no changes to the data and the response is returning everything.

---

BuildFilters() as requested:

```
function buildFilters() {
        var filters = [];

        if (!_.isEmpty(me.selectedLocationIds)) {
            filters.push({
                logic: 'or',
                filters: kendoUISettingsHelper.convertArrayToKendoOdataFilter(me.selectedLocationIds, 'LocationId')
            });
        }

        if (!_.isEmpty(me.selectedProductIds)) {
            filters.push({
                logic: 'or',
                filters: kendoUISettingsHelper.convertArrayToKendoOdataFilter(me.selectedProductIds, 'ProductId')
            });
        }
    return filters;
    }
```

Comment: Could you share your code for the `buildFilters()` function? Also, are you positive that your query _should_ be receiving changes?

Comment: The goal is to filter the result set by matching ids and have this reflected in the grid. Not completely sure what you mean by the second question.

Comment: If you are using server-side filtering, are you sure you are receiving the correct filter parameters on your server side method and also your code to filter records is working correclty ?